# How can I query a string that has an apostrophe from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

So I've got a pandas dataframe and I would like to select certain rows from it based on particular values in columns.
The following code works for me:

```
df.query('Col1 == "zz" and Col2 == "yy"')
```

and returns all the rows that have "zz" in Col1 and "yy" in Col2. However, I run into a problem if the string contains an apostrophe. e.g.

```
df.query('Col1 == "zz" and Col2 == "yy's"')
```

python throws a syntax error. I have considered just removing the apostrophe from the string but it is a location name and would be more correct to keep it. How can I fix this/what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that python is interpreting the apostrophe as a special character. Hence, the solution is to triple quote the query string, like the following:

```
df.query('''Col1 == "zz" and Col2 == "yy's"''')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that:

```
df.query('Col1 == "zz" and Col2 == "yy\'s"')
```

Answer (score 2):

Escaping special characters like the previous answer is a solid approach. Another would be to use multi-line quotes:

```py
df.query('''Col1 == "zz" and Col2 == "yy's"''')
```

Comment: Why do you call them "multi-line quotes"? I know them as "triple quotes". And I know they let you make multi-line strings, but you're not using that here.